# Java EE web application performance tuning

Tags: java, performance, web-applications, code-analysis

I need to do a performance analysis of Java EE web application and optimize the code.
Please suggest ways of doing it?
To start with, I am checking the server logs.

Comment: I think this is a very vague question. Identify a particular area and we can contribute. But in the meantime Google 'J2ee tuning' and similar

Answer (score 8):

Based on your vague question an answer can just be vague:

Depending on what you want to improve, the first rule is to measure what you want to improve. Furthermore alsways measure again after you tried to improve!

**Memory**

Regarding memory optimizations you should acquire heap dumps of the running application and analyze those. A very helpful tool for an anylysis is the [eclipse memory analyzer tools](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

**Profiling**

If you want to improve the performance and minimize runtime of code, you should start with profiling. [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) is then a good tool. To get some load on your application [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) can help you in the context of a web based application.

**Rules of Performance tuning**

First measure to identify the bottlenecks, then pick the "biggest" leaks for optimization. After optimizing measure again to verify your result. If you are not happy afterwards, start again with measuring.

**Know the real slow parts of your application**

Before even starting with measuring you should exactly identify the situations where your application is really slow, otherwise you might not notice a difference or even "de-optimize".

Answer (score 0):

Use some good java profiler and figure out problem points like high memory usage, high CPU usage etc.
Look at [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) and/or [jprofiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html). You can use their trial version for your case

Answer (score 0):

Multiple tools are available to do performance analysis.

You can use Jmeter to do some load testing and see what performance you are getting. If you find performance bad for certain features then dig into that to find the bottlenecks.

You can use JProfiler to analyse JVM of the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a application monitoring tool like [newrelic](http://newrelic.com/) , it will tell you which server side components have the slowest response times, and then it will let you drill down to which calls within that application consume the most resources, that should be a good start ...